# How to send datagrams through a unix socket from PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, unix

I'm doing:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (@socket_connect($socket, $path) === false) { ... }
```

But I get this error:

```
(91): Protocol wrong type for socket
```

Am I using any of the parameters wrong? I suspect from the second socket_create parameter. I could't find any help in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/es/function.socket-create.php

Answer (score 7):

It's maby outdated, but I've found that  this way it works properly:

```
$sock = stream_socket_client('unix:///tmp/test.sock', $errno, $errst);
fwrite($sock, 'message');
$resp = fread($sock, 4096);
fclose($sock);
```

Answer (score 4):

For Unix sockets we don't need to use `socket_connect`.

Here is a very simple working example with a sender and a receiver:

sender.php

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
socket_sendto($socket, "Hello World!", 12, 0, "/tmp/myserver.sock", 0);
echo "sent\n";
?>
```

receiver.php

```
<?php

$file = "/tmp/myserver.sock";
unlink($file);

$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

if (socket_bind($socket, $file) === false) {
  echo "bind failed";
}

if (socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 64 * 1024, 0, $source) === false) {
  echo "recv_from failed";
}

echo "received: " . $buf . "\n";

?>
```

Note that only the receiver needs to bind to an address (the unix socket file) and then use `socket_recvfrom`. The sender just calls `socket_sendto`.

Comment: check this [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43421610/4626775) for working examples in php and C

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getprotobyname()` for the 3rd (protocol) parameter?

Comment: With the name of the protocol you want to use, I guess. In a comment on the english doc page is a list of them: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.getprotobyname.php

Comment: I tried "udp", which is the one I want, but got [93]: Protocol not supported.

Comment: Hmm. Is everything included in php.ini? Also, I read somewhere that udp doesn't work with ipv6, but that's probably not it. Anyway, there are some more examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php.

Answer (score -1):

The third argument to socket_create is incorrect hence the error message.

It should be socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

The value 0 that you specified corresponds to SOL_IP which is not a supported protocol in php.

Comment: No, the reason is because it should not use `socket_connect` on a SOCK_DGRAM socket. And your `AF_INET` does not relate to the question on unix domain sockets