# php: looking for email library which supports message queuing

Tags: php, email

i'm looking for a email library for building up a newsletter system inside our company.
it should support message queuing (feeding mails to the queue, automatic mailing in the background) without blocking the webserver.
so i think background processing should be run as background service on the server,
similar to aspmail but for php.

any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used PEAR's [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/mail_queue) to queue up 200,000+ mails at a time. Populating a database is easy and quick, even with customised content, and then a fairly simple script sends around 250 a time - if the load average isn't too high. Then it loops around and sends the next batch.  That runs from the background, and Its easy to set so that if the queue table is empty, it pausing for a moment before it checks again (because checking several times a second won't help anyone).

The advantage of also checking the load average of the machine is that it will just crunch through the queue without any problems of self-created resource starvation.

The Mail_Queue [tutorial](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-queue.mail-queue.tutorial.php) gives you almost everything you need - just loop around th 'send_messages.php' script (from the command line is better) until the database queue is empty, then pause a while - and loop again.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) to build an autonomous daemon waiting for jobs submitted by your web server.

There's a nice article: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/ explaining how to create daemons in pure PHP code.

On the webserver side, you simply create jobs (gearman client), and queue them asynchronously into the gearman daemon.
Then you have your mailer php daemon waiting for jobs (gearman worker), and execute them when they become available on the queue.

If you have a huge amount of mails to send, you can even deploy the workers across several servers, that will wait on the same gearman job queue, to optimize email processing.

Answer (score 1):

> it should support message queuing (feeding mails to the queue, automatic mailing in the background) without blocking the webserver. so i think background processing should be run as background service on the serve

WTF? Managing queues is the job of the email system - its what it has been **designed** to do - it is NOT the responsibility of application talking to it. And if your mailserver blocks every time you send a message, there's something **very** wrong with it.

It sounds like you are trying to write your own MTA instead of fixing what's wrong with your current provision.

If you need to provide offline capability, then install an MTA on the machine where the PHP is running.

Comment: isn't the sendmail call blocking(relative slow) in PHP. You will notice it if you do inside your webrequest?). Especially when you need to do a lot of them?

Comment: Effectively it's an exec call - but it should **never** block for more than a fraction of a second - otherwise there's something very wrong (like a misconfigured smartHost)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [redis](http://redis.io) as your [message queue](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/):

[image: message queue]

Redis is very fast and actively developed data structure server. Writing something using redis is going to be easy as pie. Why I like redis over other message queues:

- actively developed.
- Redis:

  > an open source, advanced
  >   key-value store. It is often referred
  >   to as a data structure server since
  >   keys can contain strings, hashes,
  >   lists, sets and sorted sets.

  It is very powerful.
- Very easy to install: `make`.
- has c-bindings in almost any prefered languages.
- the c client library hiredis is very user friendly. You could write something in C if you want really good performance. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789720/communicate-c-program-and-php/4789990#4789990)(thanks to hiredis) I created just compiles using only `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of what is required I dont think theres an out of the box solution specifically for MTA duties, however I could be wrong.

I have built something similar recently, which involves putting the emails to be sent into a database queue with a field to show if its been sent or not, and then running a CRON job to process the send script for a set batch, send those emails, and mark as sent, rinse and repeat.

Would be interested to have a chat with you over email / msn just to see what you have got planned for the system seeing as I am basically doing the same thing.

Comment: just a follow up note, make sure the crons dont overlap!! :P