# PHP: Sending huge quantity of emails in batch

Tags: php, email, batch-file

Putting aside the disdain from junk marketing I need to send around 15,000 emails to customers. My coworker has tried to send them through php mail loop but obviously it gets stuck quickly. Is there a conventional (i.e. through PHP script) to accomplish this swiftly? If not, how do you suggest I do this (maybe through `exec`) without too much overhead?

Thanks!

Comment: Swift Mailer? http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used PEAR's [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/mail_queue) to queue up 200,000+ mails at a time. Populating a database is easy and quick, even with customised content, and then a fairly simple script sends around 250 a time - if the load average isn't too high. Then it loops around and sends the next batch.

You won't send them any faster than is usually possible, but it will do it without any problems.

The [tutorial](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-queue.mail-queue.tutorial.php) gives you almost everything you need - just loop around th 'send_messages.php' script (from the command line is better) until the database queue is empty.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using something like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) to create a queue system as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920973/php-looking-for-email-library-which-supports-message-queuing). Another option would be to look at a paid service like [Amazon's Simple Email Service (SES)](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you implement immediate delivery: it'll be a lengthy process that's always subject to interruptions and you can't afford restarting the delivery and sending the same message twice to 5,000 customers.

I believe that a reliable system must use queues.  The main script simply adds recipients to a queue and then you have a secondary process that picks items from the queue, get them sent and finally mark them as sent. This secondary process can be launched manually (maybe from the command line) or via cron tab.

I've never used but I have this in my bookmarks: http://ledscripts.com/free/php/phpledmailer

Comment: @symcbean - And Paris is a French city. Do your downvote and comment have any actual relation with this question?

Comment: usually you give good advice - but its virtually impossible to send emails without using a queueing system - and why implement more queueing in PHP when you already have a well written queueing system - often with many off-the-shelf add on tools for manaing the queue?

Comment: @symcbean Your seem to be confusing mail internals with client side PHP code. The whole point of this question is that if you use PHP to loop through your 10,000 row customer database (the usual approach) your script may need like two hours just to generate the messages and deliver them to the MTA. What I'm suggesting is to replace the loop with a local PHP queue. That's exactly what the accepted answer is about. (BTW, that's a better answer because it actually suggests *how* to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it through CGI or as  a script on the command line? It's best to run it as a script on the command line.

If you say that it gets stuck, try running `set_time_limit(0);` to avoid PHP quitting from the execution being too long.

Comment: I'm looking for either solution. Set time limit will still take too long to send them all. What script should I use on command line?

Comment: You don't need to change anything. PHP scripts can be run on the command line.