# Is "PEAR::Mail_Queue" effective in extensive sending of e-mail?

Tags: php, email, cakephp, pear

I am conceiving of extensive transmission of mail by PHP.
Although it seems that PEAR has the module "PEAR::Mail_Queue", is this effective?
Please let me know an advantage and a fault.

*P.S.*
I do not limit the server specification.

Comment: you should look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920973/php-looking-for-email-library-which-supports-message-queuing

Comment: Define "effective". What exactly do you want/need?