# most efficient inter-process call between PHP and C daemon

Tags: php, c, interprocess

I have a REST API backed by PHP, that calls a C program.  Depending on the inputs, the C program returns JSON data, and the PHP reads the output and directly sends it back to the client.

The code is essentially:

```
$command = $binary . " " . $parameters;
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

For each invocation of the API, PHP starts up the program, does some processing, and ends.

I would like to make this more efficient by making the C program run as a daemon, and then have the PHP backend call into this daemon.

Also, I might be migrating to a Python web framework, so I would like something that is cross-platform from the client side.

My gut reaction is to simply do it over sockets, since then I can put the daemon anywhere (it would for the foreseeable future be located on the same web server, but I could move it off eventually).  But is sockets efficient enough, or is there something else that is considered a better practice?

Comment: I've been using Gearman recently, and it'll do this no problem. Although primarily it is a queue, you can also kick off blocking workers if you want to wait in PHP until something is done. I believe workers can be written in most languages - whilst I'm using PHP again, I should think C would be no problem.

Comment: Cross platform, Cross language, distributed, fast, nice: http://www.zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789720/communicate-c-program-and-php/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this without knowing more about your C program.

One thing which is definitely worth checking is [creating a PHP extension](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/zend.creating.php).

It's not cross platform, but you can write similar extensions to Python or Ruby, and the extension part is really just a small skeleton around your C program, and it's really easy to write.

Comment: Thanks, my program is really just a small C program that returns strings based on user input.  So it's not very complex yet.  I will likely investigate zeromq though, that might be more what I'm looking for.

Comment: Link for "creating a PHP extension" (http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/zend.creating.php) **with 404 error**.